# Renaming all files in a folder with specific extension using python

Tags: python, operating-system, rename

I am using python and I'm extremely new. I have a folder with hundreds of files, I have renamed their extensions as jp,gi,jpe and mp. So, I would like to loop through all of them, rename them all according to their extension. If it's jp then jpg, if it's jpe then jpeg, gif for gi and mp4 for mp. I know that it's a lot but, answer would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> jp then jpg, if it's jpe then jpeg, gif for gi and mp4 for mp

You can first create a dictionary like this:

```
extensions={'jp':'jpg','jpe':'jpeg','gi':'gif','mp':'mp4'}
```

Then import the `os` module, and use `os.listdir(folder_path)`, followed by `os.rename()`

```
import os
folder_path='/.../.../folder'
extensions={'jp':'jpg','jpe':'jpeg','gi':'gif','mp':'mp4'}
for i in os.listdir(folder_path):
    paths=i.split('.') #==== Split the string based on the parameter
 
    if extensions.get(paths[-1])!=None: #=== If a key is not present, it returns None. So if there is another file named .docx or .txt or a folder, it will return None.
       os.rename(os.path.join(folder_path,i),os.path.join(folder_path,paths[0]+"."+extensions.get(paths[-1]))) #====os.path.join(folder_path,i) joins the folder path and file name
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't really get the code :( But I guess it will work, so cheers!

Comment: Hey @Sujay - FWIW, [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/368167/is-there-any-harm-in-voting-to-close-spam-as-long-as-you-flag) is why I suggested not voting to close spam, but just flagging. But sorry that I gave the impression (as I'm sure I did, poor phrasing on my part) that I thought you hadn't flagged *as well*. :-) Hopefully the answer to my question there is "no, makes no difference to the system." There's the social engineering aspect, but to me it's quite weak and wouldn't justify a comment. Just thought I'd explain. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch this file from directory, where all 'broken' files are located. You're welcome.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

# Get path to current dir
cwd = os.getcwd()

# Get all files in dir
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(cwd) if isfile(join(cwd, f))]


for file in onlyfiles:

    # Get the current format
    s = file.split(".")
    br = s[-1]

    if br == 'jp':
        new = 'jpg'
    elif br == 'gi':
        new = 'gif'
    elif br =='jpe':
        new = 'jpeg'
    else:
        continue

    # Change format and get new filename
    s[-1] = new
    s = '.'.join(s)

    # Rename file
    os.rename(file, s)
    print(f"Renamed {file} to {s}")
```

Comment: Thanks mate, I don't get what's happening, but I guess it'll work, I'll try it out soon, thank u!!

Answer (score 0):

First make a dictionary mapping between the "old" and "new" extensions. From what I could read (and since you have a lot of files) you could have an integrity problem of the extensions... maybe a `jjp` extension? So the mapping step is quite important...
Second for renaming the file just be careful from which position in the filesystem you run the program. Here a basic solution

```
import os

extensions = {'jp': 'jpg', 'jpg': 'jpeg', 'mp': 'mp4'}


def rename_files(dir_path, extensions):
    files = os.listdir(dir_path)

    for file in files:
        for ext in extensions:  # loop over the old extensions
            if file.endswith(ext):  # check the extension
                file_new = '{}.{}'.format(os.path.splitext(file)[0], extensions[ext])
                os.rename(os.path.join(dir_path, file_new)) # rename the files
                print('{} --> {}'.format(file, file_new))


dir_of_the_files = '.'
rename_files(dir_of_the_files, extensions)
```